Are standard medical exam questionnaires meant to invite discussion?
Let's say a patient goes to a medical examination. The doctor starts verbally going through a standardized exam questionnaire, for example, something like:

Mini-Mental State Exam
MIDAS test for migraine assessment
Epworth sleepiness scale questionnaire

My question is, at this point, is it more helpful for the patient to give maximally-brief responses to the specific questions, or, if appropriate, open up a wider conversation of the issues being brought up? In other words: should the patient avoid elaborating on the responses during a standardized questionnaire?
In my experience, it seems a little awkward at these moments, because I've never heard of a doctor declaring that a standardized questionnaire was being assessed; to the patient, it just seems like a synthetic part of the wider exam conversation, so it seems strange if the patient is expected to recognize that a standard exam is being assessed, and at that point they should refrain from elaborations in their responses.

The answer is no. The reason is as stated: to keep things brief and tidy. Some people don't like brief and tidy. They aren't the providers, who have a maybe 20 minutes in the hour to interact with patients, and 40 minutes of required paperwork. If they don't get it done during office hours, they have to spend their free time doing it. I don't like it, spouses don't like it, patients don't, schedulers don't... Noone does. It's not good for anyone except insurers who make money denying services.

On the reason these patient questionnaires exist:

The acquisition of clinical information is an essential part of the diagnostic process, but the longhand recording of this data is lengthy and frequently tedious.

Question lists like these are essentially a kind of screening exam meant to quickly assess the nature and severity of a problem. As the purpose of these questions is to cut down on the time it takes to get to the "heart" of an issue, it's best answered with a simple Y/N/number/whatever is called for.
If it doesn't get to the issue at hand adequately, the healthcare provider (HCP) should/will ask follow-up questions. If you had some difficulty answering them, you should provide the HCP with that information after the quick-response portion is finished.

...should the patient avoid elaborating on the responses during a standardized questionnaire?

In a word, yes.

I've never heard of a doctor declaring that a standardized questionnaire was being assessed...

I'm not sure I understand this statement. Why should a questioner state that? These types of questions aren't open-ended (e.g. What brings you in today?) They are designed to be quickly answered. Is the HCP reading the questions from a list and ticking off the responses? If so, it should be fairly easy to answer them as they were meant to be answered.
Frankly, I'm a bit surprised to hear that a doctor administered these questions; usually it's the nurse gathering vital signs, etc.'s duty.

to the patient, it just seems like a synthetic part of the wider exam conversation, so it seems strange if the patient is expected to recognize that a standard exam is being assessed, and at that point they should refrain from elaborations in their responses.

You should change the patient to me. Questions like Have you ever blacked out from drinking? are rarely asking for deep reflection or qualification; either you have or you haven't. How many days type questions ask for none/a number answers. Usually patients are fine with these quick questions as long as the provider gives them time to elaborate if they wish to. If the provider does not, that's something to raise with that provider.
In response to your edit, the only questionnaire I routinely did myself was the MMSE because the time it takes to answer the question matters. But there's no ambiguity involved. If the question asks to spell the word "world" backwards, that's very straightforward. Also, that test should be preceded with some explanation that puts it into perspective. ("I'm going to ask you a bunch of questions. Don't worry about them, just do the best you can, and take all the time you need.") It would be very weird indeed if out of the blue, the HCP asked you to count from 100 backwards subtracting 7 each time.

To answer a few of the questions posed here: For me, it's always a doctor asking these questionnaires (never a nurse). They're looking at the same monitor or tablet throughout the visit, so there's no signal they've switched into brief-questionnaire mode.

... And one example of a presumably-straightforward question that I find not to be the case: If asked if I'm left or right handed, I'm personally semi-ambidextrous, so I have separate lists of tasks I do with my left or right hand (and why), that for most people are all aligned. Again, that's just one example: I routinely find that these kinds of questions would give misinformation if literally answered with a single word.

@DanielR.Collins - As a doc, I know what I and most docs around me do, and as a patient, I've had to fill out a hundred of those or more. Seriously, it's not a thing. And again, why should they inform you of the source of every question? Just answer the question. (This is why I should not answer medical questions: they most often devolve into discussions.) As to you handedness, if oral, you say both, if written, you circle/tick both. "Both" invites questions if it's important, which it is in neurology, orthopedics and a very few other fields. Routinely? Personally I don't think so.

Respectfully, as written, this will probably not be the selected answer, because it's somewhat orthogonal to the question: Again, the question is not about (per link) self-administered questionnaires, it is about verbal delivery by a doctor (usually a specialist), with no signal that a questionnaire is begun, and yes there are uniformly ambiguous questions in them, literally taken.

@DanielR.Collins - It's fine not to accept the answer; it is always the OP's prerogative and I have it no other way. The truth, however, is that I'm familiar with the questionnaires and both the migraine and the sleepiness scale are self-administered tests. The EDS scale is way, way too long for a physician to conduct, and is full of questions directed to the patient, whereas the directions for the two most often employed MMSEs are directed to the physician. Which is why the doctor asks those questions. From the EDS scale: "If you have a chronic illness, meet with your...

...healthcare provider before deployment to discuss the impact this may have on your health and to adjust your medicines, if needed." Etc. These are instructions or suggestions at the bottom of several sections of questions. And, again, a doctor who reads those off (if such a creature exists) is under no obligation legally or morally to inform you of the source of "standardized" questions. You have not explained why they should, except that you feel "awkward" about it for some reason.
